# Gatsby Js, Graph QL - mapping through query, using MarkdownRemark

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, markdown, gatsby

I am new to Graphql and Gatsby so I am still learning how to access things in graphql.

I am trying to turn my markdown table into html.
Currently, my query looks like so:

```
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
  query {
    allContentfulQuestionAnswer {
      edges {
        node {
          question
          id
          answer {
            answer
            childrenMarkdownRemark {
              html
              id
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`)
```

I am trying to map through the data to get both the questions and the answers. Like so:

```
    <>
    <h1>FREQUENTLY ASKED QUESTIONS</h1>
    {data.allContentfulQuestionAnswer.edges.map( ({ node, index }) => (
        <div className="repairCost">
        <p>{ node.question }</p>
        <p>{ node.answer.answer }</p>
        </div>
      ))}
```

I have tried changing `{ node.answer.answer }`  to `{ node.answer.answer.childrenMarkdownRemark }` ...etc

When I go into the graphql playground, and I create the query:

```
  allMarkdownRemark {
    edges {
      node {
        html
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and map over that. I am able to get the markdown in html form.. however, I need it to be displayed with the question and the answer together.

Currently it looks like:
[image: markdown table]

Would appreciate all or any help!

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
<h1>FREQUENTLY ASKED QUESTIONS</h1>
{data.allContentfulQuestionAnswer.edges.map( ({ node, index }) => (
    <div className="repairCost">
    <p>{ node.question }</p>
    <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: node.answer.childrenMarkdownRemark.html }} />
    </div>
  ))}
```

Your loop looks good, however, you are not rendering the `answer` itself because you need to render HTML, that's why [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) is useful.

Since the response you are fetching is markdown-like, you may need to use a markdown interpreter in order to display it properly. There are a lot of libraries, but I will base this answer in [`markdown-to-jsx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-to-jsx):

```
import Markdown from "markdown-to-jsx";

<h1>FREQUENTLY ASKED QUESTIONS</h1>;
{
  data.allContentfulQuestionAnswer.edges.map(({ node, index }) => (
    <div className="repairCost">
      <p>{node.question}</p>
      <Markdown>{node.answer.childrenMarkdownRemark.html}</Markdown>
    </div>
  ));
}
```

Comment: thank you for you help and direction. I will look more into dangerouslySetInnerHTML for my own understanding. When I updated my code above to your suggestions, I am seeing this error 

`"Error in function assertValidProps in ./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:2706"  props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML must be in the form {__html: ...}. Please visit reactjs.org/link/dangerously-set-inner-html for more information.`

Comment: Sorry, I added an extra underscore (`_`). It should be `{{__html: node.answer.childrenMarkdownRemark.html }}`. Answer updated

Comment: Thanks! @Ferran! So that did get rid of the error, however now the "answers" do not show up.

Comment: I think that maybe `childrenMarkdownRemark` is not the node you need to query for. Because it's not raw HTML, it's markdown so you'll need a markdown interpreter (like https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-to-jsx)

Comment: Hi Ferran! So I was messing around with my code and the possible solutions you sent. I was able to use "childMarkdownRemark" in my query and use <p
                  `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: node.answer.childMarkdownRemark.html
                  }}
                />`
but it will not work for "children". 
Thank you for pointing me in the right direction though! Super helpful and I am grateful!